# Deploy Polymer Project to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, polymer

I'm studying about AWS and Polymer. Both of them, I'm newbie.
My purpose is running API Server(built by node.js) on EC2,
and running Client Polymer pages on S3.

But When I upload all files from "polymer build" command to S3 bucket,
It doesn't run correctly.
[image]

Polymer site gave me some consol errors and blank page.
[image]

After many hours with struggling, I found this page.
https://github.com/mediahack/generator-famous-polymer-gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/aws-s3-deployment.md

Is this only way that I can deploy my Polymer project to AWS S3?
I don't know about gulp. Also I couldn't find any tutorial for this. (speak with sobs)

I know the tutorial for depolying to Google App Engine or Firebase is on the Polymer documentation.
But I want depoly to S3 because as far as I know Polymer project is composed of Static Files.

At First time, I knew that all thing would be done if I upload entire Polymer Build folder and open index.html file on browser.
I don't know why I have to enter "polymer serve" command with static files.

Sorry for poor english and shallow knowledge but please help me.

Comment: It would have been a lot more helpful if you would have given more details like the path it was trying to look up file at, but i'm going to make a guess and say that you would have had your imports like `../../webcomponentsjs` instead of `../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs`. As `polymer serve` takes care of this internally it runs fine on your local, but not so for S3

Comment: @a1626 Thank you for replying. I don't know why this was happend. I deleted all files from the bucket and upload all again. Now Polymer looks working fine.(I don't think some file was missing. because I checked all files was uploaded well.) But, Thank you your comment. I'll check import path when I got this error again.